# ios Terms and conditions for my app before downloading from app store

Tags: ios, download, app-store, conditional-statements

I saw some applications on app store require the user to accept some custom terms and conditions before being able to download the app.

How can one achieve this? And does this imply Apple's terms and conditions not be valid anymore?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new app using their iTunes Connect portal (which you must), you can specify a custom EULA (End User License Agreement).

As of Apple's terms not being valid anymore, I don't think so but for further reading - these are the minimum requirements your custom EULA must meet:

http://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/appstore/dev/minterms/

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for and couldn't find.

Comment: Does this EULA compulsory to accept prior to download or update app from app store?